# Область видимости

Tags: php

```
class Main{
function make(){
    echo "a - " . $this->a . "<br>";
    echo "b - " . $this->b . "<br>"; // как сделать так, чтобы здесь были доступны переменные $a и $b? Возможно ли это вообще?
    }
}

class Child extends Main{
protected $a = "A";
}

class ChildLast extends Child{
protected $b = "B";
}

$obj = new Main(); // при этом объект создается именно для родителя(Main)
$obj->make();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить данные из родительского класса, т.к. при определении дочернего класса мы указываем (связываем, порождаем от него) другой класс.
У родителя нет абсолютно никаких данных сколько у него детей и есть ли вообще (да, да, непутёвый такой родитель...), поэтому доступа к дочерним классам нету.

В любом случае - код, который использует такие коммуникации, должен лежать [тут](http://govnokod.ru).
Как вариант решения - вызывать в потомках родительскую функцию, а аргументами передать нужные данные.
Правда тогда можно будет использовать данные только одного класса - того, кто вызвал.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Main, Child, ChildLast три разных объекта. К тому же Вы пытаетесь вытянуть объект в обратном направлении от назначения. Все что описано в Родительском классе доступно в дочернем, но не наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Капитан Очевидность любезно подсказывает - если члены наследника ну прям  позарез нужны в родителе, то их (сюрприз-сюрприз) нужно переместить из наследника в предок.
Это называется "рефакторинг", а конкретно этот прием - "Подъем поля"

Либо можно сделать функцию Main абстрактной/виртуальной и реализовать/переопределить с нужным функционалом в наследнике.